# "Attempt to present VC on VC whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" when button pressed from tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xib

Trying to build my first app. Using a TableView to present 4 different sections. Each section has its own type of cell, which is defined in a .xib file. In the last section of the TableView, a cell is presented with two buttons, plus and minus.

When, for example, the plusbutton is pressed, it calls the following code in the class related to the cell:

```
// link to the viewcontroller with the tableview in it
let mainViewController = ViewController()

// func called when plusbutton is tapped
@IBAction func plusButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // viewcontroller that should popup when the button is tapped
    let popup = PopupViewController()
    let sbPopup = SBCardPopupViewController(contentViewController: popup)
    // call to show()
    sbPopup.show(onViewController: mainViewController)
}


// show() function that is called
public func show(onViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        viewController.present(self, animated: false, completion: nil)
 }
```

When I tap the button in the simulator, it should present the PopupViewController, but the following warning shows:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present "balance1.SBCardPopupViewController:     0x7fdf8752cb20> on <balance1.ViewController: 0x7fdf8743cac0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I tried researching the warning and found some other topics relating to it. None of the solutions worked for me. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm calling the plusButtonTapped() from a cell defined in a .xib file?

I followed this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yUIOjykPDU 
All went wel untill 10:36 where the show() is called on the same VC where the button lives that calls the function. In my case the plusButton that calls the show() function lives on a cell that is defined in a separate .xib file and thus not on the (main) VC (as shown in the tutorial). Does this have anything to do with the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks like it's right. Just looking at your code the "dangling" mainViewController hasn't been added to a window yet.

```
// link to the viewcontroller with the tableview in it
let mainViewController = ViewController()
```

This comment above this line seems to indicate that it's a link to the parent viewcontroller, but it's actually a freshly instantiated viewcontroller. You'd need to pass the actual parent down through the hierarchy to achieve what you're trying.

You could make it easier on yourself if you gave each cell a "presentationDelegate" of some sort, that would handle all presentation of cards.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. Any suggestions on how to pass the actual parent VC down the hierarchy? 

My guess would be: 

func plusButtonTapped (){
....
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        
        // call to show()
        sbPopup.show(onViewController: controller)
}

(storyboard ID of the VC with the tableView in it is: "MainViewController")

Comment: Comment above is hard to read. Here with formatted code:

`func plusButtonTapped (){ .... let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainViewController", bundle: nil) let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") // call to show() sbPopup.show(onViewController: controller) } `

Comment: When you're creating the cells in : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview

You can pass in a receiver for actions in the cell itself.

Comment: Fixed the issue by getting rid of the .xib files and copying over the cells directly into the TVC. That means that I can call the show(onViewController: **self**). Solved the problem. Thanks for your help!